# Selenium WebDriver : I am not able to automate the drop down list element

Tags: selenium

Pardon me for any silly mistakes, I am still an amateur
Also I am able to run the code just the drop down selection part is not working
Here is the code

```
package com.thinksys.dd;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class Autodd 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

       System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\Users\\thinksysuser\\Downloads\\geckodriver-v0.18.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
       WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();
       driver.get("http://newtours.demoaut.com/mercuryregister.php?%20osCsid=e6b6a3a86207b80bb2d346a613c378da");

       WebElement e = driver.findElement(By.name("country"));
       Select index = new Select(e);
       index.selectByVisibleText("PORTUGAL");
    }
}
```

Comment: There is space after portugal in html dom

Comment: Doesnt work with space either.

Comment: have you tried select by value?

Comment: yes, still doesnt work.

Comment: Thanks all for your inputs, Problem solved

Comment: First perform scroll and check whether element is visi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was there due to the fact that my Firefox browser was not updated to the most recent version and since I have done that it is running just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with below code.It should work.

```
index.selectByVisibleText("PORTUGAL ");
```

Comment: @akashdeepSingh - what is the error you are getting?

Comment: I think the mistake is somewhere after select class. I am not able to get the drop down selection automated

Comment: @akashdeepsingh - can you provide the stack trace please?

Answer (score 0):

The actual issue here is not with the select class or with its methods. We are missing implicit wait here. Just add implicit wait after initiating the driver and the code works fine then.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/home/santhoshkumar/Softwares/Selenium/drivers/geckodriver");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("http://newtours.demoaut.com/mercuryregister.php?%20osCsid=e6b6a3a86207b80bb2d346a613c378da");

WebElement e = driver.findElement(By.name("country"));
Select index = new Select(e);
index.selectByVisibleText("PORTUGAL");
```

Hope this helps. Thanks.

Comment: I have used implicit as well as explicit wait..... now I think it is a browser based problem because I tried on my other system it is working fine with Thread.sleep();

Answer (score -2):

Try this code using `xpath` locator. 
 
**Note:-**  Provide few seconds of `wait` before execute below code and Instead of using `absolute` xpath, use `relative` xpath.

```
new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@name='country']"))).selectByVisibleText("PORTUGAL");
```

> OR

```
new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@name='country']"))).selectByValue("167");
```

Comment: Provide few seconds of `wait` before execute above code. Because above code is working fine on my side.

Comment: I have used implicit as well as explicit wait..... now I think it is a browser based problem

Comment: No dear, User explicit wait or provide `Thread.sleep(5000);` before execute above code. I have verify this issue on all browsers and it is working fine in all the browsers.